# C++ to C# conversion

Tags: c#, c++, function, iterator, enumerator

I am new to C#, I am doing my practice, by converting some code in C++ to C#.
But stuck here, don't know how to convert this function to C#, which take any collection, its 1st element and its last element and add an element in it.

```
    template<class _Col>
void __insert
    (
    _Col&                   collection,
    typename _Col::iterator first,
    typename _Col::iterator last
    )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        collection.insert( *first );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no direct equivalent to this code in C#.  You'll have to figure out what the outcome is and write a whole new method, not just a clone of the above.

Comment: Google c# enumerables and generic types, then give it a shot and tell us what's the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain:

1. It is a generic function.
2. It use come sort of collection. with iterators in our case `IList<Type>` interface for collection from `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

so lets get started:

as I know C# default containers did not provide iterator feature so I resplaced it by usage `IList<Type>` interface wich provide similar to iterator indices.

As you can see it is not good to do like this

```
template<class _Col>
void __insert
    (
    _Col&                   collection,
    typename _Col::iterator first,
    typename _Col::iterator last
    )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        collection.insert( *first );
    }
}
```

Because `_Col` can contain not only template collection classes but also any other class, and if this other class will not prowide proper interface the compilation process fails. The same is for iterators there are many types of it.

So I strongly suggest you to stick convention, that if you consider to use the template type as some sort of collection in function, try to use `collection<Type>` declaration on parameter, and  `funcName<Type>` on function. That will ensure you to process your data in proper way.

```
static void Insert<Type>(IList<Type> outputCollection, IList<Type> inputCollection,  int start, int end)
{
      if (end >= inputCollection.Count)
         return;

      for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
          outputCollection.Add(inputCollection[i]);
}
```